# link to newest post, excluding 2 categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

Trying to create a hyperlink on the home page that takes you to the latest blog post (in single view, ie the entire post) that excludes 2 categories.

I am linking separately to the excluded categories like this:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'category' => 23 );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );                   
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">Latest Post</a>';
    }
?>
```

but don't know how to code a link that take you to the newest post excluding categories 23 & 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer from Ross Hanney on Wordpress' forum:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 1,
    'category__not_in' => array( 23, 24 )
);

$recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent ) . '">Latest Post</a>';
}
?>
```